# Time limit editing comments

Tags: support, editing, comments

Why is there a five-minute time limit editing comments?  I found typos I wanted to correct in a comment I had posted, but it was too late, and I was forced to delete and repost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The real problem is that, second class citizens that they are, comments do not have a history.
>
> SE lets you edit pretty much everything else at any time because there's edit accountability: At any given moment, we know who changed what, when, and why. This isn't the case with comments — this is why comments can no longer be edited after the standard grace period.

[Why is the time limit for editing comments only 5 minutes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78573/why-is-the-time-limit-for-editing-comments-only-5-minutes)

TL;DR; it would open room for much abuse, which is much harder than posts to moderate.

As a solution, you can entirely delete and paste your comment in another one, if it doesn't make any other comments look stupid and mysterious.

Comment: I still don't get you @Oscar. What was the problem with reposting the comment?

Comment: I tried that @TIPS.  But it ended up breaking a link I wanted to reference, and I had to post a second comment with the restored link.

Comment: I copied the comment onto a clipboard, then deleted, then pasted the copy as a fresh comment I could correct.  But the copy was not perfect, I found out after the fact that the link had lost the http header. That's how it broke.  Can not the 5 minute limit be lifted for the comment'sowner?

Comment: Comments won't lose http with copy-paste. However, the drag-and-drop in some browsers drops those. I'm pretty sure that was the case here.

Comment: @Oscar if you want it removed for the comment's owner, feel free to make a feature request on [meta.se]. However, if you use the "search", you'd see that this is a well-discussed matter and the feature-request won't garner much support. There are more interesting feature-requests about comments, that, due to their temporary and without-log nature haven't been implemented. Sometimes, things aren't just perfect and we have to live with what we have.